# How to pull ECS docker image from an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

What is the best practice to pull a Docker image located in a repository in ECS from an EC2 instance?

- I pushed Docker images into my repository located under ECS.
- I would like to launch an EC2 instance and pull these images from it.

I am used to take advantage of the ECS task. To just run a Docker container for 5min, I need to go to `Auto-Scale`, set the minimum at `1`, go to the ECS page, wait for an instance to be up and run my task. Too annoying for my personal use. I'd like to run it quickly and stop it quickly.

I wanted to simply run my Docker container but ok, that's not possible, then I am thinking of creating an EC2 template that will directly run my Docker container inside an EC2 instance.

- How to do it?
- How can I handle the keys/users and the AWS CLI inside my EC2? (Access/Secret Access Key are limited to 30min, I can't write it clearly in the `User Data` of an EC2 instance/template)

I think my need is very basic and I couldn't find the best way to do it. Blog articles mainly explain how to run Docker on Linux, not the best way to do it on AWS.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a combination of the EC2 instance role, and a script that performs docker login followed by a `docker pull` for your pushed image.

**Pre-requisites:** An EC2 instance with the AWS CLI and Docker installed.

First, you'll have to add the inbuilt `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` IAM policy to your EC2 instance's IAM role (this grants read access to **all** pushed images). If you'd like things to be more restrictive, you can use the following policy instead:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GrantSingleImageReadOnlyAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage"
      ],
      "Resource": "<aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<image-name>"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GrantECRAuthAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, you'll have to create a script to perform login and image pull for you. A typical script would look something like this:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region <region> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com;
docker pull <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<image-name>:<optional-tag>;
```

Note that this script will have to run as the root user for proper Docker daemon access.

> Another way of solving this altogether would be to look into automation options for ECS tasks.

Comment: Important note: if you attach an IAM policy to an EC2 instance, most AWS tools will be able to find the credentials that come from that automatically; you don't need to manually set or pass around an AWS access key ID.

Comment: It's exactly what I was about to ask before reading your comment. That's very nice and I was afraid of that. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to avoid ECS tasks that are good only if we want them all the time.
Your solution is working perfectly flawlessly. Thanks Kunal!

Comment: The command is wrong, it should be "aws ecr get-login-password --region <region>| docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com"
and then can pull image 

"docker pull <aws-account-id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<image-name>:<optional-tag>"